# How to change the CUDA_CACHE_MAXSIZE NVIDIA

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, nvidia

Hello I just bought the new RTX 3080 GPU. And I want to use the Cuda for my tensorflow models. But when I start to train the model it takes more than an hour to start training it. So I went to the tensorflow website and there it said to increase the CUDA_CACHE_MAXSIZE but I dont know where that is. Can someone help me find it and make the size bigger? My GPU is 10GB. Thanks!

Comment: This is an [environment variable](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#env-vars).  The method for setting an environment variable depends on your OS (which you haven't indicated), but regardless instructions for setting environment variables are  easy to discover via google.  You can also "fix" this problem by using a version of tensorflow that is compiled for Ampere GPUs, such as what is available now on [NGC](https://ngc.nvidia.com/catalog/containers/nvidia:tensorflow)

Comment: Hello, Im using Windows 10 and I have TF 2.3.1. When I go to the environment variables there isnt the cuda_cache_maxsize am I suppose to create a new environment variable with a path to that? Where can I find the path to the cuda_cache_maxsize? Btw I installed all the cuda things with anaconda. Thanks!

Comment: yes, you need to [create a new environment variable](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+create+environment+variable)  There is no path associated with it.  You set the environment variable equal to a value based on the instructions in the first link I gave you.  And, by the way, I wouldn't be surprised if setting this variable doesn't substantially improve your start up experience.  But give it a shot.

Comment: Okay Thank You !!!

Answer (score 1):

Proving solution in the answer by combing the solution provided by *Robert Crovella* in the comment section.

`CUDA_​CACHE_​MAXSIZE` is a environment variable which comes under Compilation category. By default it will be 256 MB and Maximum is 4 GB, you can set this environment variable on your windows using below path.

```
Control Panel ->System and Security->System->Advanced System settings
```

You can follow these([1](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html#install-windows) & [2](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#env-vars))documentation for more details.